# Create petals for cylinder flower in Geometry Nodes (3.1) (question 1)

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, geometry

I've been following [a tutorial by Kaizen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf2hnWMGKEs)

I managed to get it to work the way he does it which is fine. Then I tried to apply it from the ground up step by step but doing it in a different way.

This is what I need help with:

**#1 I want to spawn a flower heart or centre, as a cylinder with X faces.** I've managed to do that okay, and I think I will add a reference to an Empty object in the scene so I can manually rotate the flower head.

How do I rotate the centre/heart so it faces up along the curves direction (or normal I suppose)? That way I can draw the curve to appropriately have the flower face a certain direction.

Also, is there a simpler way to just tell GeoNodes to spawn an object at the end of curve* (at the final vertex) without using the ColorRamp technique that he does?

[image: flower heart part of the node tree]

[image: petal object]

[image: Result so far]

Comment: please focus on one question, not two, else your question will be closed (these are the rules, i didn't make them), so just copy the 2nd part and open a new question and paste it there. thank you.

Comment: thanks for the response. could you point me to where it mentions that rule? the question was based around making a proper flower, i just split it into two to break down the steps i was looking to achieve. i would think that splitting it into two posts would dilute the question and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following setup:

1. Reverse the curve (if the start point is at the bottom).
2. Use the node `Curve to Points` and set *Count* to the value `1`. This way only one top point remains and you also get the necessary rotation for the object to be instantiated.

[image]