# Create petals for cylinder flower in Geometry Nodes (3.1) (question 2)

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

question continued from [first post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259061/create-petals-for-cylinder-flower-in-geometry-nodes-3-1-question-1)

**#2 I want to spawn a "petal" on each of the centre/heart's faces.** As you can see, in this instance, the heart is a 6 sided cylinder with no fill, and so the result would be 6 petals spawned on each face with the appropriate rotation and position.

The only thing I can think of is to Distribute Points on Faces but that seems to place random points across the faces.

[image: flower heart part of the node tree]

[image: petal object]

[image: Result so far]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following setup:

1. Use the node `Dual Mesh`. This will transform *Faces* into *Points* (and vice versa).
2. Use the *Normals* of the *Faces* as alignment.

[image]